# Rendering of pop up window is different in IE8 and IE9 using ExtJS

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, internet-explorer-9, popupwindow

I had a issue of a Pop Up box not showing completely when the main browser root element is reduced in size i.e. so the pop up window is not completely visible, because of the small window. If you go to maximize the main browser window, the pop up expands with the screen and remains as if the window were still shrunken, but only larger.

I therefore modified the code to **center** the pop up window. Though this approach works in IE8, it does not work in IE9, and newly installed Chrome. Though repair fix in Chrome works, and it works perfectly in Firefox. Anyway to fix this issue in IE9 and Chrome.

Below is the code refernce:

```
openPopUp: function (width, height, title, actionName, popupClass, popupClosable) {
    var parentIsPopup = DCT.Util.getSafeElement('_popUp').value;
    DCT.Util.getSafeElement('_popUp').value = '1';
    var interviewPopup = new DCT.PopupWindow({
        width: width,
        height: height,
        modal: true,
        title: title,
        cls: (Ext.isEmpty(popupClass)) ? null : popupClass,
        closable: popupClosable,
        dctAssignFocus: true,
        dctInterview: true,
        dctItemClass: DCT.InterviewPanel,
        dctParentIsPopup: parentIsPopup,
        dctPanelConfig: {
            dctParentIsPopup: parentIsPopup,
            dctActionName: actionName
        }
    });
    interviewPopup.show();
    Ext.getCmp('dctPopupWindow').center(); // this was the line added by me
},
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Anyone please any help on the same?.

Comment: Can you prepare a testing sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Maybe someone would be more willing to help then.